# Problems with installing CUDA enabled JAX on a WSL Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: machine-learning, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jax

I am trying to use JAX with my GPU on a WSL virtual machine, but the package throws errors when used.

I used `pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html` from https://github.com/google/jax#installation. I tried this for a miniconda installation, and later also for a completely new Ubuntu WSL, from a clean venv. Earlier, I tried a manual Jax, CUDA and Cudnn installation, which threw the same error. I have updated my NVIDIA driver on the host pc, which has a 1070ti as GPU.

I try to run a simple:

```
from jax import random
key = random.PRNGKey(0)
```

Which generates the following error:

```
2023-04-16 22:41:14.651263: W external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:397] There was an error before creating cudnn handle: cudaErrorNotSupported : operation not supported
2023-04-16 22:41:15.925044: E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1207] Failed to get stream capture info: operation not supported
2023-04-16 22:41:16.034579: E external/xla/xla/pjrt/pjrt_stream_executor_client.cc:2432] Execution of replica 0 failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: stream is uninitialized or in an error state
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XlaRuntimeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/root/ML/JaxTest.py in line 2
      1 from jax import random
----> 2 key = random.PRNGKey(0)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/random.py:136, in PRNGKey(seed)
    133 if np.ndim(seed):
    134   raise TypeError("PRNGKey accepts a scalar seed, but was given an array of"
    135                   f"shape {np.shape(seed)} != (). Use jax.vmap for batching")
--> 136 key = prng.seed_with_impl(impl, seed)
    137 return _return_prng_keys(True, key)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:270, in seed_with_impl(impl, seed)
    269 def seed_with_impl(impl: PRNGImpl, seed: Union[int, Array]) -> PRNGKeyArray:
--> 270   return random_seed(seed, impl=impl)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:561, in random_seed(seeds, impl)
    559 else:
    560   seeds_arr = jnp.asarray(seeds)
--> 561 return random_seed_p.bind(seeds_arr, impl=impl)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:360, in Primitive.bind(self, *args, **params)
    357 def bind(self, *args, **params):
    358   assert (not config.jax_enable_checks or
    359           all(isinstance(arg, Tracer) or valid_jaxtype(arg) for arg in args)), args
--> 360   return self.bind_with_trace(find_top_trace(args), args, params)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:363, in Primitive.bind_with_trace(self, trace, args, params)
    362 def bind_with_trace(self, trace, args, params):
--> 363   out = trace.process_primitive(self, map(trace.full_raise, args), params)
    364   return map(full_lower, out) if self.multiple_results else full_lower(out)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:817, in EvalTrace.process_primitive(self, primitive, tracers, params)
    816 def process_primitive(self, primitive, tracers, params):
--> 817   return primitive.impl(*tracers, **params)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:573, in random_seed_impl(seeds, impl)
    571 @random_seed_p.def_impl
    572 def random_seed_impl(seeds, *, impl):
--> 573   base_arr = random_seed_impl_base(seeds, impl=impl)
    574   return PRNGKeyArray(impl, base_arr)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:578, in random_seed_impl_base(seeds, impl)
    576 def random_seed_impl_base(seeds, *, impl):
    577   seed = iterated_vmap_unary(seeds.ndim, impl.seed)
--> 578   return seed(seeds)

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py:817, in threefry_seed(seed)
    812 k1 = convert(
    813     lax.shift_right_logical(seed, lax_internal._const(seed, 32)))
    814 with jax.numpy_dtype_promotion('standard'):
    815   # TODO(jakevdp): in X64 mode, this can generate 64-bit computations for 32-bit
    816   # inputs. We should avoid this.
--> 817   k2 = convert(jnp.bitwise_and(seed, np.uint32(0xFFFFFFFF)))
    818 return lax.concatenate([k1, k2], 0)

    [... skipping hidden 8 frame]

File ~/ML/MLVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py:1916, in ExecuteReplicated.__call__(self, *args)
   1911   self._handle_token_bufs(
   1912       results.disassemble_prefix_into_single_device_arrays(
   1913           len(self.ordered_effects)),
   1914       results.consume_token())
   1915 else:
-> 1916   results = self.xla_executable.execute_sharded(input_bufs)
   1917 if dispatch.needs_check_special():
   1918   out_arrays = results.disassemble_into_single_device_arrays()

XlaRuntimeError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: stream is uninitialized or in an error state
```

Finally, I also tried installing the cuda11 version, with the same results, except the `W external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:397]` error is not thrown. What could cause this error?

Comment: I have the same error. Tried it with docker with different images, and also with nvidia/cuda image. But the same problem persists. Did you find solution to your problem? I have 1060GTX.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found information what is going on - I had the same problem with 1060.
XLA has a bug that prevents jaxlib from working on pascal gpu. The bug has been fixed but still jaxlib needs to be built with this new version.
You can try compiling it yourself if you follow jax tutorial how to build jax from sources or you can wait for official release.

[Jax bug](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/15260)

Edit:
The bug should be fixed in nightly release (not stable!). In order to properly install jax issue this commands:

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/google/jax 

pip install jaxlib --pre -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jaxlib_nightly_cuda_releases.html
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up temporarily using the CPU version due to time constraints but I will try this later.

Comment: you can try jax 0.4.6 which should work on gpu on Pascal.

Comment: @Strange_Grass There is a fix and I have edited my answer. Please let me know if that works for you?

Comment: thank you for editing your answer. I'll be able to try this in the next few days.

Comment: Hmm i get this error:

` E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:427] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.5.0 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.`

I'll try to see if I can use any different (more recent) builds. Any idea what would work @emot?

Comment: It looks like there was an old CUDA version on my WSL which made your fix not work. I installed a clean distro after which installing JAX with CUDA 12 now works with the single pip command provided in their install readme.

Comment: @Strange_Grass yeah I think that bug was fixed in jax 4.09 or 4.10, therefore single pip now works.